# innodb_file_per_table doesn't work

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb

I am trying to use the `innodb_file_per_table` option of my mysql 5.0.

my relevant my.cnf is:

```
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:100M:autoextend  
innodb_file_per_table 
innodb_autoextend_increment = 100
```

but when i drop & recreate my schema & DB, i see the split files for tables, but they are too small! (they dont start from 100MB)

what can be the problem?

thanks!

Comment: If you are using the xfs file system, you can have xfs pre-allocate contiguous disk space for your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innodb_autoextend_increment` only affects the shared tablespace.

You can set neither the initial size nor the increment size for the per-file tablespaces:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,26788,63040#msg-63040